# Does the Mobius Strip have an homogenous embedding?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, isometry, homogeneous-spaces

So in this question I’m trying to do two things at once. 1. Define what a “homogenous embedding” is by describing what it is like and then furthermore ask if such an embedding exists for the mobius strip.

We start with the first part. A manifold is homogenous, loosely, if every point is like every other point in a “rigid” sense ie there are isometries of the manifold sending one point to the other. Examples of this are the following:

1. The real line, or any line in $\mathbb{R}^n$. any point can be mapped to any other point by shifting the line. So all points are kind of the same.
2. The perimeter of a circle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, any point can be mapped to any other point by rotation so again all points are kind of the same.
3. The surface of a sphere (which naturally embeds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or higher, any point can clearly be rotated to any other point.
4. The surface of an infinite cylinder embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We can translate or rotate any point to any other (notice with a finite cylinder there is a clear difference between boundary points and interior points so this really HAS to be infinite and can be viewed as $S_1 \times R$ where the homogenous group actions from those factors gives rise to the homogenous group action for the whole space)
5. A torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$ this one is a little tricky to see. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the torus isn’t homogenous because most obvious the inner perimeter has a different length than the outer perimeter. In $\mathbb{R}^4$ it becomes possible to draw a torus so that all perimeters are identical in length and so we can really, say all points are identical with a natural action of $S_1 \times S_1$ acting on them.

So now we get to the meat of the question. What about the mobius strip? Is there a way to embed an infinite mobius strip in $\mathbb{R}^4$ or higher so that it doesn’t self intersect and really is homogenous? IE every point is basically identical, meaning for any pair of points there is a function from the manifold to itself that preserves all relative distances and maps one point to the other?

It’s not clear to me if this is possible but I do feel optimistic.

Comment: The Möbius strip is compact so any embedding of it in 3-space would be bounded.

Comment: In part (4) i bring  up the infinite cylinder. I point out there that a finite cylinder would naturally have issues being a homogenous space and similarly the compact/finite Mobius strip has the same issues. So that’s why we explicitly point out the “infinite Mobius strip”. But yes your comments are valid if we didn’t consider the infinite version

Comment: An open Moebius band admits no homogeneous Riemannian metrics.

Comment: This question is closely related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410275/is-the-moebius-strip-riemannian-homogeneous

Comment: you might be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414402/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-moebius-strip-as-a-linear-group-orbit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6):

I think you're confounding "homogeneous" and something about embeddings.

The cylinder with the product metric is (metrically) homogeneous because for any point $(\alpha, C)$, the map
$$
(\theta, s) \mapsto ((\theta + \alpha) \bmod 2 \pi, s + C)
$$
sends the point $(0, 0)$ to $(\alpha, C)$ in a metric-preserving way.

The embedded cylinder in $3$-space, $$
\{(\cos t, \sin t, u) \mid 0 \le t < 2\pi, u \in \mathbb R 
\}
$$
happens to be a lot like that abstract manifold, and there is a linear isometry taking any point (like, say $P = (1, 0, 0)$) to any other point $(\cos t, \sin t, u)$, where $t$ and $u$ are fixed, and taking the whole cylinder to itself; the isometry in this case is $(x, y, z) \mapsto (\cos(a + t), \sin(a + t), z+u)$m
where $a$ is any angle whose cosine and sine are $x$ and $y$ respectively.

There might be some other isometric embedding of the abstract cylinder that does not admit any linear isometry of 3-space taking each point to each other point (e.g. if you did an isometric embedding of the circle as an eccentric ellipse rather than a as a round circle).

So the first question I think you need to ask is "is the infinite mobius strip with the "product" metric in fact homogeneous in the first sense?"

**Then** there's the followup: is there an isometric embedding $f$ of $M$ in some $\mathbb R^k$ with the property that for any $P, Q \in F(M)$, there's a linear isometry $T_{PQ}$ of $\mathbb R^k$ such that

1. $T(P) = Q$
2. $T(f(M)) = f(M)$ as sets

My own offhand guess about the first question is that the answer is "no" -- (1) the "centerline" of the Mobius band is special and (2) if you want to take a (non-centerline) point $A$ on some ray to a different (non-centerline) point $B$ on that ray "stretching all rays by the same amount" doesn't work. So the right question is probably something like this:

"For certain pairs $P, Q$ of points on the mobius strip $M$, there's an isometry $S_{PQ}$ of $M$ taking $P$ to $Q$. Is there an embedding $f$ of $M$ in $\mathbb R^k$, for some $k$, with the property that for every such pair, there's a linear isometry $T_{PQ}$ of $\mathbb R^k$ such that $$
T_{PQ}(f(A)) = f(S_{PQ}(A))
$$
for all $A \in M$?"

Is that in fact what you want? If so, then I have a little bit of an answer: Writing $M$ as $[0, 2\pi] \times \mathbb R / \sim$, where "$\sim$" is the smallest equivalence relation for which $(0, t) \sim (2\pi, -t)$, I suspect that the isometries of $M$ look like (a) "rotation in the $S^1$ direction, with flipping as you pass $2\pi$," and (b) reflection ($t \mapsto -t$) in the $\mathbb R$ direction, and combinations of these.

In that case, the desired embedding in 4-space is a lot like the flat torus. You send the point $(\alpha, t)$ to
$$
(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha, t\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}, t\sin \frac{\alpha}{2})
$$
and the "rotational" isometries are realized by multiplication by matrices like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta &  -\sin \theta & 0 & 0 \\
\sin \theta &  -\cos \theta & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
while the "reflection" isometry is represented by multiplication by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Separating OPs questions into two parts is good and correct but it turns out that the answer to part (1) is indeed yes if one allows a Möbius strip that of width $\mathbb{R}$ as explained in the answer by Sammy Black

Comment: See my answer for a proof that a Moebius band admits no homogeneous metrics.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is simply wrong, there are no such things as "translations in the parameters (,), where  is considered modulo 2." I will prove below that the open Moebius band does not admit any homogeneous Riemannian metrics. However, Moebius band does admit flat metrics, which are (obviously) **locally** homogeneous, i.e. for any two points $p, q\in M$  there are neighborhoods $U, V$ of, respectively, $p, q$, and an isometry $U\to V$.

Let's first convince ourselves that "translations" do not exist for any values of the parameter $t\ne 0$ and $s=0$. The supposed formula for such a translation is
$$
T: (x,y)\mapsto (x, y+t). 
$$
However, $(0,y)$ is equivalent to $(1,-y)$ and we get $T(1,-y)=(1, -y+t)$. But for $T$ to be well-defined as a map of the Moebius band, you have to have that $T(2\pi,-y)=(2\pi, -y+t)$ is equivalent to $(0, y+t)$, implying that $-y+t= -(y+t)$, i.e. $t=0$.

Now, let's proceed with a general proof. Suppose that $g$ is a homogeneous Riemannian metric on the Moebius band $M$. The actual definition of homogeneity simply means that the isometry group of the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ acts transitively on $M$, i.e. for any two points $p, q\in M$ there exists an isometry $f: (M,g)\to (M,g)$ sending $p$ to $q$ (you will find this definition in pretty much any textbook on Riemannian geometry). It is known that every homogeneous Riemannian manifold is **complete** (see for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581912/homogeneous-riemannian-manifolds-are-complete-trouble-understanding-proof) question). Since $M$ is noncompact, completeness of $(M,g)$ implies that it has infinite diameter (this follows for instance from the Hopf-Rinow theorem). Now, let $C$ denote the **central circle** of the Moebius band. More precisely, in the notation of the accepted answer, this is the projection to $M$ of the interval
$$
\{ [x, 0]: x\in [0,1]\}. 
$$
The circle $C$ has the property that for every self-diffeomorphism $f: M\to M$, $f(C)\cap C\ne \emptyset$ (same is true for self-homeomorphisms). You need to know a bit of differential or algebraic topology to verify this. (Briefly, the mod 2 fundamental class of $C$ generates $H_1(M, Z_2)\cong Z_2$ and the self-intersection of this class is nonzero.)

Now, suppose that $g$ is a homogeneous Riemannian metric on $M$ and $d$ is the corresponding distance function on $M$. Let $D$ denote the diameter of $C$ in $(M,d)$, i.e.
$$
D=\max_{p, q\in C} d(p, q). 
$$
For every isometry $f$ of $(M, g)$, the diameter of $f(C)$ is also $D$. Now, using the fact that $M$ has infinite diameter, find a point $q\in M$ such that $d(q, C)\ge 2D$, where
$$d(q,C)=\max\{ d(q,p): p\in C\}.$$
Let $f$ be an isometry of $(M,g)$ such that $q\in f(C)$ (such an isometry exists by the homogeneity assumption). Since $f(C)\cap C\ne \emptyset$, let $p$ denote a point of this intersection. Then $$2D\le d(q, C)\le d(q,p)\le D.$$ A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for writing this, let me take some time to digest this, perhaps my intuition of requiring an isometry is too much, and there is some function that is like an isometry but not exactly which let’s us create a weaker notion of a homogenous space than the standard one which then allows us to construct what we want.

Comment: Ok I’m starting to see what the issue here is. There’s no real notion of translation “up” and “down” the strip due non orientability. Yet @Sammy’s construction seems like it really is “the same” everywhere. And it does look like you can vary the $t$ parameter though this doesn’t correspond to any kind of translation in this normal sense.

Comment: I love that half-topology, half-geometry argument --- very satisfying.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistake and writing this answer. :-)

Comment: Isn't there an elementary argument for why $f(C) \cap C \neq \varnothing$ for any self-homeomorphism that just uses the intermediate value theorem from calculus? Or is that only for sections of the bundle?

Comment: @SammyBlack: I doubt that an IVT will be of any use here. As for an elementary argument which avoids any algebraic topology: Maybe, but one would have to account for some potentially very complicated self-homeomorphisms of $M$ which do not preserve the bundle structure. Personally, I prefer the intersection theory argument.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is an embedding, although **as pointed out in the comments of the question and in response to this answer,** the homogeneous property fails due to non-orientability. This infinite Möbius strip is often referred to as the *nontrivial line bundle over the circle* and can be thought of abstractly as the space
$$
X = ([0, 1] \times \mathbb{R})/{\sim}, 
$$
where the equivalence classes are singleton points except at the boundary, where $(0, t) \sim (1, -t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

How to embed this space isometrically in some $\mathbb{R}^N$ though? Just as there's an isometric embedding of the torus $S^1 \times S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ built out of the embedding $S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (see the [Clifford torus embedding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Clifford_torus)), we can do something similar for $X$. Here's a parametrization:
$$
\begin{cases} 
x = \cos s \\
y = \sin s \\ 
z = t \cos \frac{1}{2}s \\
w = t \sin \frac{1}{2}s 
\end{cases} 
\qquad 
s \in [0, 2\pi], \quad 
t \in \mathbb{R}  
$$
This describes a line in the $zw$-plane of slope $\tan \frac{1}{2}s$ "over" the point $(\cos s, \sin s)$ in the $xy$-plane. Notice that the line is parametrized in opposite directions at $s=0$ vs $s=2\pi$: $(z, w) = (t, 0)$ vs $(z, w) = (-t, 0)$, respectively.

<strike>As for your rigid homogeneity, any translation in the parameters $(s, t)$, where $s$ is considered modulo $2\pi$, i.e. translation by an element of the Lie group $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, will map a point in your space to another point with identical local geometry.</strike>

Comment: +1, but it might be good to point out explicitly that this is an embedding, not just an immersion, since the question included "it doesn't self-intersect."

Comment: Translation in the $t$ direction is not well-defined in the Mobius strip as it does not preserve the equivalence relation

Comment: This doesn't work because translation in $t$ is not an isometry.  Look at what happens if you try to translate the circle $[0, 2\pi]\times\{0\}$ to $[0, 2\pi]\times\{1\}$.

Comment: wow.  you lost me at nontrivial.  +1

Comment: The last paragraph is simply wrong.

Comment: @sammy if two different line bundles are homeomorphic but not isotopic do we say that they are still equivalent as line bundles? I guess I’m just using this as a lazy way to ask “is a line bundle a topological notion or a geometric notion?” Since it feels like a geometric notion to me as a literal bundle of lines on a circle

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my silly error, @DavidMoews...

Comment: ... and @MoisheKohan

Comment: Okay in light of all the comments, is there some way to make rigorous the idea that your parametrization is the “nicest”/“most symmetric”/“most natural” paramterization. And that while shifting by $s,t$ are not legally isometries they are still ___ which lets us say in some strict sense that all the points of the moenius strip given by your parametrization  are kind of the same.

Comment: Oh wait are those parameter shifts all locally flat? Then that might be good enough. I just re read Moishe’s post

Answer (score 3):

Although, as Moishe Kohan has pointed out, the open Moebius strip has no homogeneous Riemannian metric, there is a metric tensor $g$ for the open Moebius strip $M$ giving it a transitive group of isometries.  However, this metric tensor is indefinite, and doesn't come from an embedding of the strip into ${\Bbb R}^n$. (**Added**:  That is, the construction in this post doesn't construct it from an embedding.  As Moishe Kohan has pointed out in the comments, you could find an isometric embedding of $(M, g)$ into some pseudo-Euclidean space ${\Bbb R}^{p,q}$.  Given the poster's question, though, it seems better to find some metric on $M$ so that it can be embedded into ${\Bbb R}^{p,q}$ and so that the group of isometries of ${\Bbb R}^{p,q}$ induces a transitive group of isometries on $M$.  I don't know whether that's possible for this metric or for any other.)

To see this, coordinatize the Moebius strip by $t$, $u\in \Bbb R$, where we identify the points $(t, u)$ and $(t + \pi, -u)$, coordinatize ${\Bbb R}^3$ by $x$, $y$ and $z$, and give ${\Bbb R}^3$ the metric
$$
ds^2=-dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.
$$

We also identify $(x,y,z)\sim (-x,-y,-z)$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$.
Then we can embed the Moebius strip into ${\Bbb R}^3/\sim$ via
$$
(t,u)\mapsto (\sinh u, \cosh u \cos t, \cosh u \sin t)
$$
and give it the induced metric.
The image of the strip is the quotient of the one-sheeted hyperboloid
$$
H=\{(x,y,z)\mid -x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}
$$
by $\sim$.  Any matrix $N\in O_{1,2}({\Bbb R})$ (meaning any 3 by 3 real matrix $N$ with $$N^T\left(\begin{array}{ccc}-1 & \ & \ \\ \ & 1 & \ \\ \ & \ & 1 \end{array}\right)N=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}-1 & \ & \ \\ \ & 1 & \ \\ \ & \ & 1 \end{array}\right)),$$ will preserve the metric in ${\Bbb R}^3$ and send $H$ into itself; also, $v\sim w$ implies that $Nv\sim Nw$.  So, any such $N$ induces an isometry on the Moebius strip. Then, the isometry group of the strip is transitive since any point on $H$ can be sent to a point $(x, y, 0)$ on $H$ via some rotation around the $x$ axis,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & \ & \ \\ \ & \cos \theta &  \sin \theta\ \\ \ & -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array}\right)\in O_{1,2}({\Bbb R}),
$$
and any point $(x, y, 0)$ on $H$ can be sent to $(0, 1, 0)$ via the matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}y & -x & \ \\ -x & y &  \ \\ \ & \ & 1  \end{array}\right)\in O_{1,2}({\Bbb R}).
$$

Comment: It is a general and obvious fact that an indefinite metric on any manifold cannot be induced by embedding a manifold in a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't come from an embedding into ${\Bbb R}^n$ equipped with an indefinite metric.

Comment: I see, but such a statement is false: Every semi-Riemannian manifold embeds isometrically in $R^{p,q}$ for suitable $p$ and $q$. You probably mean that there is no equivariant isometric embedding. This might be true but you did not prove it.

Comment: When I wrote the sentence, I was thinking of the construction in the answer; I didn't mean to make a general claim.  I revised my post.  Hopefully, it's clearer and more correct now.

Comment: For a proof of existence of isometric embeddings, see R.Greene, "Isometric Embeddings of Riemannian and Pseudo-Riemannian Manifolds", Memoirs of AMS, 1970, vol. 97.